# SQL return values as fields based on key and value type table - PIVOT, CASE, etc?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, pivot

Using SQL Server 2005 I have the following tables:

Value:

```
ValueID  UserID    ValueTypeID  ValueKey  Text  Number
------------------------------------------------------
1        345       1            NAME      Bob   NULL
2        345       2            AGE       NULL  30
3        689       1            NAME      Sam   NULL
4        689       2            AGE       NULL  45
```

ValueType:

```
ValueTypeID  CodeName
---------------------
1            TEXT
2            NUMBER
```

And I wish to get results like:

```
UserID  Name  Age
-----------------
345     Bob   30
689     Sam   45
```

I am sure this is possible, using a pivot and maybe some case statements?  There are more ValueKeys, and even more ValueTypes but this will get me going.  I know the list of ValueKeys in advance, so this should mean I can avoid a dynamic query.

Answer (score 1):

A classic pivot query. Then you can use the ValueTypeID if you want:

```
SELECT UserID, 
       MAX(
           CASE WHEN ValueKey = 'NAME' 
                THEN 
                    CASE WHEN ValueTypeID = 1 
                             THEN Text 
                         WHEN ValueTypeID = 2
                             THEN Number 
                         WHEN ValueTypeID = 3
                             THEN Date
                         ELSE NULL
                    END
                ELSE NULL 
           END
       ) AS Name,
       MAX(
           CASE WHEN ValueKey = 'AGE' 
                THEN 
                    CASE WHEN ValueTypeID = 1 
                             THEN Text 
                         WHEN ValueTypeID = 2
                             THEN Number 
                         WHEN ValueTypeID = 3
                             THEN Date
                         ELSE NULL
                    END
                ELSE NULL 
           END
       ) AS Age,
       MAX(
           CASE WHEN ValueKey = 'DATEBIRTH' 
                THEN 
                    CASE WHEN ValueTypeID = 1 
                             THEN Text 
                         WHEN ValueTypeID = 2
                             THEN Number 
                         WHEN ValueTypeID = 3
                             THEN Date
                         ELSE NULL
                    END
                ELSE NULL 
           END
       ) AS DateBirth
FROM Value
GROUP BY UserID
```

But it is maybe useless, you can just be less generic with less code:

```
SELECT UserID, 
       MAX(
           CASE WHEN ValueKey = 'NAME' 
                THEN Text -- I know that name is a string
                ELSE NULL 
           END
       ) AS Name,
       MAX(
           CASE WHEN ValueKey = 'AGE' 
                THEN Number -- I know that age is a number
                ELSE NULL 
           END
       ) AS Age,
       MAX(
           CASE WHEN ValueKey = 'DATEBIRTH' 
                THEN Date -- I know that date of birth is a date
                ELSE NULL 
           END
       ) AS DateBirth
FROM Value
GROUP BY UserID
```

Comment: How would I extend this to deal with a date of birth key  and another valuetype of DATE?

Comment: +1, you can also omit `ELSE NULL`, because it is implied if `ELSE` is not specified.

Answer (score 0):

The resolution should be to redesign the table. The valueType lookup is completely useless as-implemented. You should just have a single "ValueText" column instead of "Text", "Number", ... and store all values in that 1 column. Then it would be a simple `join` statement.

Comment: Unfortunately I am querying a legacy database.  I am unable at this point to change its design.  Also the Text is a nvarchar field, the number is an int field, there is also a date field of datetime type etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can group by UserID and use a sub-query to get the field values.

```
declare @T table
(
  ValueID int,
  UserID int,
  ValueTypeID int,
  ValueKey varchar(10),
  Text varchar(10),
  Number int
)

insert into @T values
(1,        345,       1,            'NAME',      'Bob',   NULL),
(2,        345,       2,            'AGE',       NULL,    30),
(3,        689,       1,            'NAME',      'Sam',   NULL),
(4,        689,       2,            'AGE',       NULL,    45)

select T1.UserID,
       (select [Text]
        from @T as T2
        where T1.UserID = T2.UserID and
              T2.ValueKey = 'NAME') as Name,
       (select Number
        from @T as T2
        where T1.UserID = T2.UserID and
              T2.ValueKey = 'AGE') as Age
from @T as T1
group by T1.UserID
```